# PHP include page from GET and page title

Tags: php, html, security, http, seo

I want to include page in page like index.php?page= php echo GET

Because I need security in first place I would like to know how to make the follow code better and secure but I do not know how. The pages will be stored only in a special folder /pages/ with only pages.

The problem is that index.php uses the same metatags so it is not SEO friendly. How can I change page title and keywords using the follow code in index.php?page=

```
<?php
$unsafe = $_GET['pagename'];
$page = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/', '', $unsafe);
if (empty($page)){
include('pages/default.php');
}
$pages = array('default', 'pageone', 'pagetwo', 'another', 'last');
if (isset($pages[$page])) {
    include('pages/' . $page . '.php');
} else {
include('pages/error-404.php');
}
?>
```

EDIT

I found a code that maybe can help with title and metatags. But still need help improving the security. Do you think the follow code I found may help?

```
<?php
function do_html_head($title,$keywords,$description)
{
// print an HTML head
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title><?php echo $title;?></title>
<META NAME="keywords" CONTENT="<?php echo $keywords?>">
<META NAME="description" CONTENT="<?php echo $description?>">
}

And then I apply it on the page where I need it like:


<?php
do_html_head('title text','keywords text','description text');
?>
```

Comment: Hmm.. In which page do you currently set metatags?

Comment: index.php and the script code is in body of this page to show only content but because the index.php is static and only include all other pages into its body I get stuck

Comment: The current "protection strategy" by `preg_replace()` does not make much sense. You should check if the page exists. That is the only thing that matters. And you should do so by first sanitizing the content, checking if it is a path or not and then look for the file.

Comment: how to sanitize the content? This script will not connect to MySQL. Can I get hacked? I am learning

Comment: The way you suggested in question (after Editing) should work fine. 

Still - don't go too far in this direction. You will make bigger steps if you start use a framework. You can find a list of frameworks here: http://www.sitepoint.com/best-php-frameworks-2014/